# How to call the javascript function in mvc action result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have made a JavaScript function `IPDetection()` and I want to call this function from an MVC action result. How can I do this?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function IPDetction() {
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (key == 'city') {
                    alert("DetectedCityName=" + val);
                }
                if (key == 'region') {
                    alert("DetectedRegionName=" + val);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `@ViewBag` for this purpose like:-

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult YourActionName()
{
    ViewBag.CallJSFuncOnPageLoad = "IPDetction();";
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @Html.Raw(ViewBag.CallJSFuncOnPageLoad)
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this ... this is code is correct and working fine ......but one problem is occurred ..Please also see this .. I have fetch the DetectedCityName and DetectedRegionName in Contoller from this script so please give me the solution for this......Thanks again...........

Comment: @SRAspNet you can make an ajax call and send those as param to be processed on server side.